# Is it okay to use two different API's on the same project for a different activities?

Tags: security, django-rest-framework, fastapi

HI I'm Currently working on a web app project
I have some doubts regarding the API and its security
My question is , Is it okay to use Rest API and Fast API on the same project for a different activities?
Any security or other issues when I'm using these two API's in same project?

Please advise me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't Fast API already a Rest API?

Comment: @Zimano Hi Thank you for the reponse ,  Im new in API. can you elaborate lill more?

Comment: What's the reason for using FastAPI if you're already using django rest framework? Use DRF if you have a django app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no definitive answer, but in general it is considered bad practice to use multiple API frameworks within the same project. This is because each framework has its own set of conventions and best practices, which can lead to confusion and inconsistency. It is usually best to choose one framework and stick with it.